fmthard/prtvtoc: what is wrong?
I want to understand how to make a new slice without using format.
This is the original situation (working)
* /dev/rdsk/c0t2d0s2 partition map
*
* Dimensions:
*     512 bytes/sector
*      63 sectors/track
*     255 tracks/cylinder
*   16065 sectors/cylinder
*    5220 cylinders
*    5218 accessible cylinders

*
* Flags:
*   1: unmountable
*  10: read-only
*
* Unallocated space:
*       First     Sector    Last
*       Sector     Count    Sector 
*    41495895    369495  41865389
*
*                          First     Sector    Last
* Partition  Tag  Flags    Sector     Count    Sector  Mount Directory
       1      9    00      16065  20980890  20996954
       2      5    01          0  83827170  83827169
       3      9    00   31487400  10008495  41495894
       8      1    01          0     16065     16064

The partitions size (better slice) are 10gb for first, 5gb for second and 4.77gb for third.
I want to create a fourth slice (number 4) with a size of 2GB and reduce the third to 2gb
I edit this file (saving the old as a backup)
* /dev/rdsk/c0t2d0s2 partition map
*
* Dimensions:
*     512 bytes/sector
*      63 sectors/track
*     255 tracks/cylinder
*   16065 sectors/cylinder
*    5220 cylinders
*    5218 accessible cylinders
*
* Flags:
*   1: unmountable
*  10: read-only
*
* Unallocated space:
*       First     Sector    Last
*       Sector     Count    Sector
*    41495895    369495  41865389
*
*                          First     Sector    Last
* Partition  Tag  Flags    Sector     Count    Sector  Mount Directory
       1      9    00      16065  20980890  20996954
       2      5    01          0  83827170  83827169
       3      9    00   31487400  4194304   35681703
       4      9    00   35681704  4194304   41865389
       8      1    01          0     16065     16064

The size seems to be correct (2048 mb for each slice)
4194304*512 = 2147483648
2147483648*1024 = 2199023255552
2199023255552/1024 = 2147483648
2147483648/1024 = 2097152
2097152/1024 = 2048

But when I try to create the new partition table..
fmthard -s file.map /dev/rdsk/c0t2d0s2  
Partition 3 not aligned on cylinder boundary: "       3      9    00   31487400  4194304   35681703"

Where is my fault?
I know with format is too easy, but I want to learn this way too.

Solution/workaround found. I follow the "cylinder rule".
You can create any size you want (of course without exceeding the disk size and), but every slice must be "composed" of a tot of cylinders which must be "bind" to a slice, for example: partition 1 use 1-1000 cylinders, 3 use 1001-1500 (id 2 is ignored because it refer to entire disk), etc. and this is correct, partition 1 use 1-1000 cylinders and 3 use 1000-1500 is not correct because a cylinder cannot be "shared", first calculate the size of cylinder, to avoid boring math calculation I have create a slice of 1 cylinder with format
  3 alternates    wm    1307 - 1307        7.84MB    (1/0/0)       16065

So If I want to create a 3000mb slice i have to calculate how many 7.84mb units (cylynder size) I can use to "reach" 3000mb
I made those calculations
3000/7.84 #3000 is partition size in mb 2.93g approx
382       #composed of 382 cylinders (result of 3000/7.84)
382*16065 #16065 is the number of sectors for each cylinder

The finally result is 6136830 sectors (2.93gb) and is the result of 382*16065
So I edit the file to use first partition of 10gb, the second third and fourth of 3000mb.
*     512 bytes/sector
*      63 sectors/track
*     255 tracks/cylinder
*   16065 sectors/cylinder
*    5220 cylinders
*    5218 accessible cylinders
*
* Flags:
*   1: unmountable
*  10: read-only
*
* Unallocated space:
*   First     Sector    Last
*   Sector     Count    Sector 
*    20996955  10490445  31487399
*    41495895  42331275  83827169
*
*  
*
*                          First     Sector    Last
* Partition  Tag  Flags    Sector     Count    Sector  Mount Directory
       1      9    00      16065  20980890  20996954
       2      5    01          0  83827170  83827169
       3      9    00   27133785   6136830  33270614
       4      9    00   33270615   6136830  39407445
       8      1    01          0     16065     16064

Will work? Yes
sudo fmthard -s file.map /dev/rdsk/c0t2d0s2  
fmthard:  New volume table of contents now in place.

Testing newfs and mount works.
EDIT: I also found not all size works, if fail I found this workaround
This configuration don't work
      1      9    00      16065  16787925  16803990
      2      5    01          0  83827170  83827169
      3      9    00   16803991  16787925  33591916
      8      1    01          0     16065     16064

this one yes (i remove 1 sector from end size of previous partition and I add +1 to start of next partition, finally -1 sector remove from endsector of last/next partition)
   1      9    00      16065  16787925  16803989
   2      5    01          0  83827170  83827169      
   3      9    00   16803990  16787925  33591915
   8      1    01          0     16065     16064

waiting for a better explanation and right formula to calculate for every partition size, I will consider this workaround valid.
EDIT2: I have tried my workaround, and works fine.
I want to add a 9GB partition
This configuration give me error of "Partition 4 not aligned on cylinder boundary"
   1      9    00      16065  16787925  16803989
   2      5    01          0  83827170  83827169
   3      9    00   16803990  16787925  33591915
   4      9    00   33591916  18876375  52468291
   8      1    01          0     16065     16064

This works perfect
   1      9    00      16065  16787925  16803989
   2      5    01          0  83827170  83827169
   3      9    00   16803990  16787925  33591914
   4      9    00   33591915  18876375  52468290
   8      1    01          0     16065     16064

even newfs don't return any error (except a warning for some sectors unallocated)
sudo newfs /dev/rdsk/c0t2d0s4   
newfs: construct a new file system /dev/rdsk/c0t2d0s4: (y/n)? y
Warning: 4138 sector(s) in last cylinder unallocated
/dev/rdsk/c0t2d0s4:     18876374 sectors in 3073 cylinders of 48 tracks, 128 sectors
        9217.0MB in 193 cyl groups (16 c/g, 48.00MB/g, 5824 i/g)
super-block backups (for fsck -F ufs -o b=#) at:
 32, 98464, 196896, 295328, 393760, 492192, 590624, 689056, 787488, 885920,
 17996704, 18095136, 18193568, 18292000, 18390432, 18488864, 18587296,
 18685728, 18784160, 18874400

